# Java - Will invoking a static method invoke the method on all instances?

Tags: java, class, static, invoke

Suppose I have a class `A`, with it's own instance variables. It has a method called `doSomething()`, which is a `static` method. Now, `A` adds another class `B` as some pointer. Say inside class `B`, I run some logic and determine that I need to run the code contained in `doSomething()`. Is it ok for me to just say `A.doSomething()`? And if I have an instance of `A` called `a`, does `a`'s `doSomething()` method get invoked?

Comment: you are a mathematician aren't you?

Comment: I'm sorry? What do you mean?

Comment: I would suggest, just write down the code and put some print statements in the methods. Execute the code ad see what happens.

Comment: what do you mean by "`A` adds another class `B` as some pointer" and "I have a class `A`, with it's own instance variables."?

Comment: @vijay `A` runs some code that is contained in an instance of `B`. I'm sorry if that wasn't too clear

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you invoke `A.doSomething()` it will just execute that static method. Saying `a`'s `doSomething` does not make sense because static methods do not belong to an object or instance of your class.

Answer (score 2):

Static methods don't belong to any particular instance. So when you call A.doSomething(), it doesn't matter if there are 0, 1, or a million instances of A. One method is called.

Answer (score 2):

the answer to your first question: "Is it ok for me to just say `A.doSomething()`?"
Yes it is. As pointed out by the other answers as well... `doSomething()` being `static` is a class method and hence does need the creating objects of A for its invocation.

the answer to your second question:"And if I have an instance of `A` called `a`, does `a`'s `doSomething()` method get invoked?"
As a matter of fact it will, but it is similar to saying `A.doSomething()`. and hence, it makes no sense invoking it in that fashion. If anything, it will add to your confusion later when you read the code.

Answer (score 0):

While I question some of your terminology (I get the feeling you know what you're talking about, you just didn't say it perfectly), to answer your question, no because it can't. A static method is tied to a class. Calling a.staticMethod() is the same as A.staticMethod. Both do the exact same thing.